# How to retrieve zookeeper host details from Kafka brokerslist

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have list of Brokers for my Kafka cluster.  How can I get the zookeeper host using Brokerslist?

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question right you want to register your brokers at a zookeeper cluster. This actually works the other way round: You have to tell each broker where your zookeeper-server (or cluster) can be found. Have a look at the broker configuration setting `zookeeper.connect`. Together with the `broker.id` it will register each broker at the zookeeper cluster.

Example:

```
broker.id=1
zookeeper.connect=zk-host-1:2181,zk-host-2:2181,zk-host-3:2181
```

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: My requirement is that I have brokerslist.  Needs to find the zookeeper host detalis for these brokers.  Tried with the below code, but it is showing broker host, not the zookeeper's.

Comment: Properties props = new Properties();
  props.put(CommonClientConfigs.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, this.brokerList);
  AdminClient adminClient = AdminClient.create(props);
  
  System.out.println("Brokers --->"+adminClient.bootstrapBrokers());
  
  scala.collection.immutable.List<Node> brokerNodeList = adminClient.bootstrapBrokers();
  Iterator<Node> iterator = brokerNodeList.iterator();
  while (iterator.hasNext()) {
   Node nd = iterator.next();
   System.out.println(nd.id());
   System.out.println(nd.host());
  }

Answer (score 1):

You cannot.

Zookeeper is intended to be abstracted away. There is no such API or method to get Zookeepers connected to a broker.

You'll need to SSH to a broker in that list (which you could do from Java}

Comment: Yes @cricket_007, you are correct.  Gone through all the source code, there is no such API to get the Zookeeper host based on Brokerlist.